# Operator-precedence grammar

Tags: formal-grammars

I can't get what is the operator-precedence grammar...  I need to convert this grammar to the grammar of weak precedence but I can't get it even.
What does this notation mean `A -> aXYb`? What's `a`, `X`, `Y`, `b`? Can someone show a real sample of OPG (grammar + some built expression)? How many start states can it have?
I tried to read but got a nothing almost.

Comment: I suggest picking up a book or lecture notes on compiler design, such as the [dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Compiler_Design). All the basics should be covered there. Regarding the notation $A \to aXYb$, this is a production in a (presumably) context-free grammar, material which is usually learned in a course about formal languages.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, thank you for the link!  I tried to read another book of Aho but I got a nothing, unfortunately...